# Parse: How to query a class using subqueries?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how to structure a query.

I have a class called Car.

Each Car is owned by a certain business. So:

Car A.business = "b1", createdAt = "May 2nd..."
Car B.business = "b1", createdAt = "May 3rd..."
Car C.business = "c1", createdAt = "April 5th..."
Car D.business = "d1", createdAt = "June 1st..."

etc..

So a business can have many cars.

I want to fetch all cars found in the database, but, only the latest car per business.

So the result would be:

Car B,C,D

In addition to that each car has an "availability date range", defined with a startDate and an endDate.

So for example:

Car A.business = "b1", createdAt = "May 2nd...", "startDate = Jun 1st", "endDate = Jun 7th"

Car B.business = "b1", createdAt = "May 3rd...", "startDate = May 20th", "endDate = Jun 3th"

Car C.business = "c1", createdAt = "April 5th...", "startDate = May 10th", "endDate = Jun 30th"

Car D.business = "c1", createdAt = "April 7th...", "startDate = May 10th", "endDate = Jun 30th"

Car E.business = "d1", createdAt = "June 1st...", "startDate = May 12th", "endDate = Jun 13th"

I am not an expert in queries, so, this might be pretty easy, just not sure how to get it done at the moment. Do I need to use subqueries? What if besides saying the latest (based on the createdAt) I also want to say: only show me those from a startDate to an endDate.

So: Show me all cars that are available now, but only the latest car per business.
The result would be (if I define now as Jun 4th):

C,D,E

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it is the easiest one for sure

```
SELECT max(car_date), car_name FROM cars GROUP BY car_name
```

I tested it and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that grouping is possible with parse queries. I guess the only way to achieve this would be to find all available cars and filter manually:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Car")
query.whereKey("startDate", lessThan: now)
query.whereKey("endDate", greaterThan: now)

query.orderByDescending("business")
query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // manually filter objects (due to the order you always need the
    // first car when the business changes)
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

Depending on the number of entries this might be feasible.